# Tello Can't Land

Tags: python, tello-drone

I was trying to control Tello by python, but the drone couldn't land; it always shows the decryption of the message in the drone was wrong. Here's the output:

```
[INFO] tello.py - 421 - Send command: 'land'
[INFO] tello.py - 445 - Response land: 'unknown command: land`P'
```

The drone has fallen from the air for a time, so is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just find out what the problem is. I've notice that (for all apple silicon users) if the computer is currently in connection with the drone through the "Tello" app, is error shows up. I think that closing the app will help. Hope this helps some m-series users!

Answer (score 0):

i think I know what ur problem is. if the drone can take off, but not land .. then check if your code looks like this:

(this is a basic example of takeoff land .. i cannot 'fix' ur code cuz u didnt show it)

```
from djitellopy import Tello
import time
tello=Tello()
tello.takeoff() # works just fine!
time.sleep(2)
tello.land() # returns error!
```

and this needs to work fine. most people forgot the "()" at the end of the `tello=Tello()` and the `tello.takeoff()`

hope it helps, enjoy!